# Views REST Export and Multi-Value Fields

Tags: views, 8

I'm having trouble getting the Views REST export to work nicely with multi-value fields.
I have an image field that can have multiple images. I have added the field to my REST export View, however all values are being output on the same line. Like this:

```
[
    {
        "nid": "11",
        "image": "http://example.com/sites/default/files/2016-02/mobile-1.jpg\n,   http://example.com/sites/default/files/2016-02/mobile-2.jpg\n"
    }
]
```

What I would like to achieve is something like this:

```
[  
   {  
      "nid":"11",
      "image":{  
         "0":"http://example.com/sites/default/files/2016-02/mobile-1.jpg\n",
         "1":"http://example.com/sites/default/files/2016-02/mobile-2.jpg\n"
      }
   }
]
```

Is this possible? 
Perhaps using HOOK_views_pre_render() to change the returned value?

Comment: I think this happens because it's displaying in the same row for that field. Unfortunately when you uncheck this, it will make each image its own row so you'd end up with multiple items for each node. However if you use entity display styling, then you should be able to use display modes to control what fields you want. Of course then you lose the ability to add field aliases.

Comment: @mradcliffe I guess this still isn't possible?

Comment: See below answer if it was reported as a bug.

Answer (score 1):

This looks like it's a plain bug. Please report it to the `views.module` issue queue in Drupal core: https://drupal.org/project/issues/drupal?component=views.module.

Comment: For reference, there is this issue: https://www.drupal.org/project/drupal/issues/2782909

Answer (score 0):

This happens even in 8.4, so I had to use the [Views Field View](https://www.drupal.org/project/views_field_view) plugin to create a view for just the list items (in your case, a list of image URLs) and add that view as a field to the main view. This works conceptually, but the output of the child view is littered with HTML which I can't seem to figure out a way to get rid of.